# Lightweight-as-possible UI stack for mobile HTML5 dev with Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, mobile, single-page-application

I'm about to build a fairly simple 'energy use issue tracker' HTML5 mobile app (Android/iOS Webkit only) using Angular. I want to avoid frameworks like HTML5Boilerplate, and use as few js libs as possible, and avoid anything JQuery; neither are we using node.js. The only UI features I really need are **screen transitions** (preferably CSS3-based with hardware acceleration), and to **avoid the 300ms tap delay**. I've been considering [angular-mobile-nav](https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-mobile-nav), but am interested in what others have chosen.

For now, this will be a 'save to home screen' single-page webapp so users can submit an issue (e.g. lights are on, no-one in the building'), take and attach a pic, and view/filter a list of issues already submitted, each of which can be up-voted and Tweeted. There's an existing REST backend the app will PUT/POST to, and we'll be using Server-sent events to update a list on the app.

None of that is too hard (I have the camera working and the backend is up and running), but *finding a minimal Angular-friendly solution for a lightweight UI* is holding me up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) will let you reach your target specially [UI Boostrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on Twitter Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required. The only required dependencies are AngularJS (minimal version 1.0.4 or 1.1.2) and Bootstrap CSS and regarding the size of the library minified version is around 40 KB.

I hope my answer help you and Please feel free to ask me any question? and I will be happy to answer.

Comment: Thanks - looks like I can just use the AngularUI modules I need, too. Since I know CSS backwards, I'm just wondering if I could avoid Twitter Bootstrap CSS (I like to write my own) but if not, I could probably prune it to get rid of unwanted/unused declarations.

Comment: Bootstrap's CSS is actually required, but you can take only parts which you need.

Answer (score 6):

consider ionic framework, Ionic is a beautiful front-end framework for developing hybrid mobile , it is still in beta version , but there is an active community working on it
http://ionicframework.com/

Comment: Thanks Sidali, I'll take a look before starting my next Angular project.

Comment: Bear in mind that ionic is only compatible with ios 6+ and Android 4.1+.

Comment: And, as already stated, it's not production-ready yet. Worth watching, though.